# Parsing many files at once with Nokogiri/Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, nokogiri

I have a main parse method that is composed by other methods that parse html files:

```
class Parser
  def self.parse(html)
    @data = Nokogiri.HTML(open(html))
    merged_hashes = {}

    array_of_hashes = [
      parse_title,
      parse_description,
      parse_related
    ]
    array_of_hashes.inject(merged_hashes,:update)

    return merged_hashes
  end

  def self.parse_title
    title_hash = {}

    title = @data.at_css('.featureProductInfo a')
    return title_hash if title.nil?
    title_hash[:title] = @data.at_css('.featureProductInfo a').text

    title_hash
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

So I do this in Rspec:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/parser.rb'

def html_starcraft
  File.open("amazon_starcraft.html")
end

describe ".parse_title (StarCraft)" do
  let(:title_hash) { Parser.parse html_starcraft } 

  it "scraps the featured product title" do
    expect(title_hash[:title]).to eq("StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty (Bradygames Signature Guides)")
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm only parsing one file at a time. How can I do it to parse many at the same time? Say, parsing all the files within a folder?

Comment: You can only parse one file at a time because Nokogiri only handles one at a time, which limits your code to that. If you want to process all the files in a directory you'll need to loop over them and sequentially parse each one, and store the parsed information as is appropriate for your code. See `Dir[]` and `Dir.glob` or `Find.find` for how to loop over the files in a directory or directory hierarchy.

Comment: Add an example using processes, you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

as @theTinMan pointed out, Nokogiri only handles one file at time. If you want to parse all files in a folder, you will have to read the folder (again, as pointed by @theTinMan) and [spawn a process](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Process.html#method-c-fork) or [thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-run) for each.

Of course you need to understand [how fork works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) or [what is a thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) first.

### Example using processes

Ok, lets use a process, since ruby doesn't have real threads:

```
files = Dir.glob("files/**")

files.each do |file|
  # Here the program become two: 
  # One executes the block, other continues the loop
  fork do 
    puts File.open(file).read
  end
end

# We need to wait for all processes to get to this point
# Before continue, because if the main program dies before
# its children, they are killed immediately. 
Process.waitall
puts "All done. closing."
```

and the output:

```
$ ls files/
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt  d.txt
$ ruby script.rb 
Content of a.txt
Content of b.txt
Content of d.txt
Content of c.txt
All done. closing.
```

Note that since it is concurrent, the order of reading the files changes every time the program is executed.

Comment: You could make good small code to complete the answer,you have that scope to do here. Could you please give that effort. I am weak in this subject although,otherwise I would add it. :) :)

Comment: @Babai added an example you might want to check